# nmcli: How to escape comma and other characters for shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, openvpn, nmcli

At first I imported an `.ovpn` file. But I want to add the username and the password. So i thought to use `nmcli modify` is the best soultion, or?

```
PASSWORD="pass,word"
nmcli con modify vpn_connection vpn.data "username=$USER" vpn.secrets "password=$PASSWORD"
```

But I get the error messsage:

```
Error: Changing faild. vpn.secrets: ",word" is invalid. Use <Key>=<Value>.
```

I tried to escape the password, but this doesn't work.

```
PASSWORD="pass,word"
printf -v var "%q" "$PASSWORD"
nmcli con modify vpn_connection vpn.secrets "password=$var"
```

I also tried the `--escape`-flag (description: escape columns separators in values), but also this doesn't help.

```
nmcli -e con modify vpn_connection vpn.secrets "password=$PASSWORD"
```

The version of `nmcli` is 1.2.6.

Comment: Try `... "password=\"$PASSWORD\""`.

Comment: @NickD Doesn't work.

Comment: `vpn.secrets` is a "dict of string to string" with a default value of `{}`. Did you mean `'{ password = "$PASSWORD" }'`?  (I don't know what type of dicts are used, it may be `'{ password: "$PASSWORD" }'` instead).  Ref: https://www.mankier.com/5/nm-settings#Description-vpn_setting

Comment: @Kusalananda Doesn't work. The ``vpn.data`` is also a dict.

Comment: Related: [Import VPN config files to NetworkManager from command line](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/140163)

Comment: Try single quotes rather than double quotes, i.e. `PASSWORD='pass,word'`, or maybe `"password='pass,word'"` in the `nmcli` command.

Comment: First don't use upper case for variables. Then note it is not bash where the problem is. You don't need to quote `,` in bash. The problem is in how the command is interpreting its arguments. What are the rules for it?

Comment: @DavidYockey Both doesn't work. Sorry.